# Use BCP To Copy When Data Has Apostrophe In It

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

Anytime my data has an apostrophe in it, the data is automatically split into the next field (which is skewing the result set).  Let's say this is my DDL

```
Create Table OneTwoThree
(
    userid varchar(max)
    ,name varchar(max)
    ,data varchar(max)
    ,data1 varchar(max)
    ,data2 varchar(max)
)

Insert Into OneTwoThree Values
('bb12', 'Hi Blee', 'Drop It Like It''s Hot', '', 'Boop')
```

And this is the `BCP` command I am using

```
Select @sql = 'bcp "SELECT ''userid'',''name'',''data'',
''data1'',''data2'' 
UNION ALL SELECT CAST([userid] As VARCHAR(MAX)),
CAST([name] As VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST([data] As VARCHAR(MAX)),
CAST([data1] As VARCHAR(MAX)),
CAST([data2] As VARCHAR(MAX)) dbo.OneTwoThree" queryout "'
SET @sql = @sql + 'C:\BCPTest.csv' + '" -c -t, -T -S '+ @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

This syntax will place "Drop It Like It" in data and "s Hot" in data1 when the entire phrase should go in data and data1 should be blank.

How should I alter this procedure so that the hyphen does not cause improper splitting?

Comment: Where does the data go?  eg if it's to another SQL Server, you should be using the native format (-n) switch.  If you really need a text file consider an alternate delimiter such as pipe (|).  Finally, you could a text qualifier using SSIS.

Comment: @wBob - this is going to a .csv file and emailed out.  Where would I set an alternative delimiter such as a pipe?

Comment: The -t switch is for field terminator, eg `-t"|"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you are expecting the .csv file to be opened using Excel or some equivalent.  I'd recommend wrapping the outputted text columns in double-quotes, such as:

```
declare @sql VARCHAR(1000);

Select @sql = 'bcp.exe "SELECT ''"userid"'',''"name"'',''"data"'',
''"data1"'',''"data2"'' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT CHAR(34) + CAST([userid] As VARCHAR(MAX)) + CHAR(34)
, CHAR(34) + CAST([name] As VARCHAR(MAX)) + CHAR(34)
, CHAR(34) + CAST([data] As VARCHAR(MAX)) + CHAR(34)
, CHAR(34) + CAST([data1] As VARCHAR(MAX)) + CHAR(34)
, CHAR(34) + CAST([data2] As VARCHAR(MAX)) + CHAR(34)
FROM dbo.OneTwoThree" queryout "'
SET @sql = @sql + 'C:\temp\BCPTest.csv' + '" -c -t, -T -S '+ @@servername
PRINT @sql;
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

The output will look similar to:

[image]

If the `BCPTest.csv` is then opened with Excel, the double-quotes will be automatically interpreted as indicating those columns are text columns, and Excel will not show the quote marks.  Therefore, you only want to wrap text (`CHAR, VARCHAR, NVARCHAR` etc) columns in `CHAR(34)`.

At that point, you'll start to see issues with columns that contain double-quotes; however you might decide to use the `REPLACE()` function to convert them into single-quotes or some other innocuous character.

Comment: What does adding CHAR(34) to the beginning and the end of the conversion do?

Comment: it wraps the output in double-quote marks.  Thereby encapsulating the data from each column.